# If First Graph Not Clicked, 2nd Graph Does Not Load (Plotly Dash)

Tags: python, click, plotly-dash, choropleth, plotly-express

I am working on a Dash Plotly project visualizing US Presidential elections data.  One part of my project shows a county choropleth map that can be changed by choosing a different state.  To the right of this map is the % of the vote both parties earned for each election for any county.  This second graph is populated by clicking on the choropleth county map.

This all works fine, but the issue I'm having is, when I switch states, the choropleth map updates just fine, but the second graph goes blank and doesn't populate until I click on the map again.

I tried to work around this by just setting the 2nd graph to first show the 1st county alphabetically upon switching states before a county is clicked.  However, it does not seem to work properly.

Here is a brief snippet of my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import dash
import os
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from flask import Flask, Response

with urlopen(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/geojson-counties-fips.json"
) as response:
    counties = json.load(response)

data = [
    ["Delaware", "Kent County", 10001, 0.467, 0.517, -75.513210, 39.156876, 2012],
    ["Delaware", "New Castle County", 10003, 0.322, 0.663, -75.513210, 39.156876, 2012],
    ["Delaware", "Sussex County", 10005, 0.559, 0.428, -75.513210, 39.156876, 2012],
    [
        "District of Columbia",
        "District of Columbia",
        11001,
        0.0712,
        0.913,
        -77.014468,
        38.910270,
        2012,
    ],
    ["Delaware", "Kent County", 10001, 0.498, 0.449, -75.513210, 39.156876, 2016],
    ["Delaware", "New Castle County", 10003, 0.327, 0.623, -75.513210, 39.156876, 2016],
    ["Delaware", "Sussex County", 10005, 0.591, 0.371, -75.513210, 39.156876, 2016],
    [
        "District of Columbia",
        "District of Columbia",
        11001,
        0.041,
        0.928,
        -77.014468,
        38.910270,
        2016,
    ],
    ["Delaware", "Kent County", 10001, 0.471, 0.511, -75.513210, 39.156876, 2020],
    ["Delaware", "New Castle County", 10003, 0.307, 0.678, -75.513210, 39.156876, 2020],
    ["Delaware", "Sussex County", 10005, 0.550, 0.438, -75.513210, 39.156876, 2020],
    [
        "District of Columbia",
        "District of Columbia",
        11001,
        0.053,
        0.921,
        -77.014468,
        38.910270,
        2020,
    ],
]


data = pd.DataFrame(
    data,
    columns=[
        "State",
        "County",
        "fips_code",
        "perc_gop",
        "perc_dem",
        "lon",
        "lat",
        "year",
    ],
)
state_choices = data["State"].sort_values().unique()

app = dash.Dash(__name__, assets_folder=os.path.join(os.curdir, "assets"))
server = app.server
app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.Div(
            [
                dcc.Dropdown(
                    id="dropdown1",
                    options=[{"label": i, "value": i} for i in state_choices],
                    value=state_choices[0],
                )
            ],
            style={"width": "100%", "display": "inline-block", "text-align": "center"},
        ),
        # State Map with County Choropleth
        html.Div(
            [dcc.Graph(id="state_map")],
            style={"width": "50%", "display": "inline-block", "text-align": "center"},
        ),
        # Party Line % Graph
        html.Div(
            [dcc.Graph(id="party_line_graph")],
            style={"width": "50%", "display": "inline-block", "text-align": "center"},
        ),
        html.Pre(id="click-data"),
    ]
)


@app.callback(Output("state_map", "figure"), Input("dropdown1", "value"))
def update_figure3(state_select):
    new_df = data[data["State"] == state_select]

    avg_lat = new_df["lat"].mean()
    avg_lon = new_df["lon"].mean()

    fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(
        new_df,
        geojson=counties,
        locations="fips_code",
        color="perc_gop",
        color_continuous_scale="balance",
        mapbox_style="carto-positron",
        zoom=6,
        center={"lat": avg_lat, "lon": avg_lon},
        opacity=0.5,
        labels={
            "State": "State",
            "County": "County",
            "perc_gop": "% Republican",
            "perc_dem": "% Democratic",
        },
        hover_data={
            "fips_code": False,
            "perc_gop": False,
            "State": True,
            "County": True,
            "perc_gop": True,
            "perc_dem": True,
        },
    )
    fig.update_layout(
        margin={"r": 0, "t": 0, "l": 0, "b": 0}, coloraxis_showscale=False
    )
    return fig


@app.callback(
    Output("party_line_graph", "figure"),
    Input("dropdown1", "value"),
    Input("state_map", "clickData"),
)
def update_figure4(state_select, click_county_select):
    if click_county_select is not None:
        new_df = data[data["State"] == state_select]
        county_id = click_county_select["points"][0]["customdata"][3]
        new_df2 = new_df[new_df["County"] == county_id]
    else:
        new_df = data[data["State"] == state_select]
        county_id = new_df["County"][0]
        new_df2 = new_df[new_df["County"] == county_id]

    fig = go.Figure()
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            x=new_df2["year"],
            y=new_df2["perc_gop"],
            name="GOP %",
            line=dict(color="firebrick", width=4),
        )
    )
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            x=new_df2["year"],
            y=new_df2["perc_dem"],
            name="DEM %",
            line=dict(color="royalblue", width=4),
        )
    )
    fig.update_layout(height=350, title=f"Results from {county_id}")
    fig.update_layout(
        title={"x": 0.5, "xanchor": "center", "yanchor": "top"}, yaxis_tickformat="%"
    )
    return fig


app.run_server(host="0.0.0.0", port="8051")
```

Can someone please help direct me to the piece that I'm missing?  Any help would be appreciated!
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line in your `update_figure4` callback (inside the `else` statement):

```
county_id = new_df["County"][0]
```

If you load the page and select `District of Columbia` in the dropdown the value of `new_df["County"]` is the following:

```
3     District of Columbia
7     District of Columbia
11    District of Columbia
Name: County, dtype: object
```

As you can see there is no row with an index of `0` in the data returned so `new_df["County"][0]` will fail.

`new_df["County"][3]` would work in this case, but the problem with this is of course that there probably isn't always going to be a row with index `3` in the data set either when you access it in the callback.

Instead use [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
county_id = new_df["County"][0]
```

**Update based on comment**

> if I click a county even just once and THEN switch to a new state from the dropdown menu, the second graph goes blank again

The reason for this is that you also need account for the case when a county is selected, but this county doesn't correspond to the state selected in the dropdown.

Since you already have logic in your `else` clause that gives a default value to the graph on the right if no county was selected you could use that same logic when the county from the click data doesn't correspond to the selected state.

So you could do something like this:

```
if click_county_select:
    new_df = data[data["State"] == state_select]
    county_id = click_county_select["points"][0]["customdata"][3]
    new_df2 = new_df[new_df["County"] == county_id]

    counties = new_df["County"].values
    if county_id not in counties:
        new_df = data[data["State"] == state_select]
        county_id = new_df["County"].iloc[0]
        new_df2 = new_df[new_df["County"] == county_id]
else:
    new_df = data[data["State"] == state_select]
    county_id = new_df["County"].iloc[0]
    new_df2 = new_df[new_df["County"] == county_id]
```

*Now I've just lazily copy pasted the code in the `else` clause in the new `if` statement, but you could extract the reused logic in its own function and call this multiple times in line with don't repeat yourself.*

Comment: Hey @Bas van der Linden! Thank you!  This helps get rid of the error, however the behavior is mostly unchanged.  If I select a new state from the dropdown menu without clicking on a county, I get the behavior I'm looking for - however, if I click a county even just once and THEN switch to a new state from the dropdown menu, the second graph goes blank again.

Comment: @user2813606 I've updated my answer to address this.

Comment: Thank you!  This is exactly what I was looking for!  Appreciate the help!